# I need to open a file in an echo statement in another tab

Tags: php, tabs, echo

When I Click the link in the php echo statement the file is open in the page itself. I want the file to open in another tab.

I know `target="_blank"` needs to be used but how to input it in my code:

```
echo <div align=center><a href='$files_show'>$files_field</a></div>";
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your problem? What exactly keeps you from adding stuff to the given output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<div align=center><a href='".$files_show."' target='_blank'>$files_field</a></div>";
```

> The target attribute specifies where the linked document will open
>   when the link is clicked. The default is the current window. If
>   target="_blank", the linked document will open in a new tab or (on
>   older browsers) a new window.
>   [Source](http://Read%20more:%20https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#ixzz5lKqH1jZL)

Answer (score 1):

try adding the blank target

```
echo "<div align=center><a href=\"$files_show\" target=\"_blank\">$files_field</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use single quotes and double quotes to use php variables in anchor link like below.

```
echo "<div align='center'><a href='".$files_show."' target='_blank'>".$files_field."</a></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `<a>` attribute `target="_blank"`.

This attribute opens the link in a new tab or in a new window depending upon the browser settings.

```
echo '<div align="center"><a href="'. $files_show .'" target="_blank">' . $files_field .'</a></div>';
```